# WSO2 AM (1.10.0) connect to RabbitMQ through JMS

Tags: wso2, rabbitmq, wso2-api-manager

WSO2 AM (1.10.0) and RabbitMQ (3.6.5) are used in my organization. I was just wondering if someone is able to show me how to connect WSO2 AM to RabbitMQ that acts as a buff to which Api Manager push information.

Thanks a lot,
Sean